# 'tokenizer.IntValue' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'

Tags: pdf, text, itext, extract

I was wondering if anyone else had hit the above problem while trying to extract text from PDF file. The first line in the PDF file is `%PDF-1.4`. The file is not corrupted as it's visible with the standard viewers.

**The code that I am using is :**

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    // For each page we tokenise the data and then build up a string of the 
    // string tokens. Spaces seem to the a string token so we get them too.

    PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(pdfReader.GetPageContent(i));
    while (true == tokenizer.NextToken())
    {
        if (PRTokeniser.TK_STRING == tokenizer.TokenType)
            stringWriter.Write(tokenizer.StringValue);
    }
}
retVal = stringWriter.ToString();
```

And has been working fine with other documents that start with `%PDF-1.5`.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: *The file is not corrupted as it's visible with the standard viewers* - that is no indication to trust... viewers often are quite forgiving because there are so many broken PDFs in the wild. Please supply the PDF for analysis; otherwise it's virtually impossible to deduce whether the PDF or iTextSharp has an issue here.